# Bootstrap muliti column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<section id="home-area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
        <p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
        <p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
        <p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
        <p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
        <p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
        <p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

I want to use bootstrap framework.

I have taken bootstrap `'col-md-12'.`

I have taken  right sidebar in `'col-md-4'.`

I want to use rest of col as  (col-md-2)*4 under col-md-8. But (col-md-2)*4 is not setup well in under 'col-md-8'.

Comment: no padding no margin. (col-md-2)*4 not setting in to col-md-8

Comment: Can you add your code below?

Comment: why don't you add a rough sketch of what you exactly need..! like a mockup..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to split a column in some part, you've to add a `div.row`

And a div separate in `4 area => col-md-3 (12/4 = 3)`

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/170FkEhdNB)

**Code** :

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
<p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
<p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
<p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
<p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
<p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
<p>Right Sitebar content goses herpe</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for active response. Your code is very useful.